# ZXing.Net.Mobile customising scannable area in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing.net

There is an overlay feature available in the library. The overlay feature is nice but functionality wise it is just there to mask the UI.

Is there a way to customize the scannable area, I mean reduce the area that is scannable on the screen? When this can't be done there is no point in having the overlay right? The overlay does not really do anything.

This android app which uses the core Zxing library developed in java by the Zxing team https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android you can see that - if the barcode/qr code lies outside the scanning area, it does not process it. That is what I am looking for. Is this possible?

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/87

Comment: So there is no such functionality exists in the Zxing.Net.Mobile library at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/87

the author of the library says

> Unfortunately there's not a great short fix that I can think of for this scenario. Yes I could only check a certain region, but what would the region be set to? It makes sense to use the non-gray areas if you're using the default overlay, but if you use a custom overlay, you might not want the same region checked.
>   Just need some time to implement it (on ALL platforms - which is what takes so much effort).

It has been a more than a year since this issue was raised on github, so I don't think it will be implemented anytime soon.